# overflow:"hidden" won't work as expected for child component (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a parent component which I would like to use for every screen of my app, as follows:

```
const ScreenContainer = ({ children }) => {
  const style = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      padding: 20,
      overflow:"hidden"
    }
  });

  return <View style={style.container}>{children}</View>;
};
```

It does add padding however padding still seems to overflow my child components even though I set it as hidden.

You can see top and bottom of the screen is being cut off for my ScrollView below:[image]

Comment: I'll write an answer please tell me if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @LouaySleman I want a vertical padding as well however I don't want the padding to overflow the content of ScrollView like it does in the screenshot. I can fix it by setting the padding inside the ScrollView however that way I would have to add padding to every single page.

Comment: I'll update my answer in one moment.

Comment: I have updated it :D

Comment: @LouaySleman same issue still persists sadly :/ also your example link seems to be working fine with my original styling as well. it doesn't work for both ios and android

Comment: You will need to move the scroll view to the screenContainer I'll update the example

Comment: I have update the answer, hope it solve your issue and if it's please mark it as correct and upvote it :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get your question right but `overflow` controls how children are measured and displayed. `overflow: hidden` causes views to be clipped

If you want to keep the top and the bottom without cutting you will need to allow the scroll from the main and pass some properties to control it in your page like this:

```
const ScreenContainer = ({ enableScroll, noPaddingHorizontal, noPaddingVertical, children }) => {
  const style = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      paddingHorizontal: noPaddingHorizontal ? 0 : 20,
    }
  });
  const Container = enableScroll ? ScrollView : View;
  return (<Container style={style.container}>
     <View style={{paddingBottom: noPaddingVertical ? 0 : 40}} />
     {children}
     <View style={{paddingBottom: noPaddingVertical ? 0 : 40}} />
  </Container>);
};
```

You can check a working example from [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@louay12/react-native-main-view).

And you can add custom header inside it and control it using props just like `noPaddingHorizontal` :D